Possible to use TSDAE for word discovery?
I am trying to identify novel words similar to one that I have encoded. From what I have been reading online, the majority of systems which look for word similarity have a predefined list of words and the encodings for said words are used in similarity calculations. But what I am trying to do is identify unknown words that are similar to my word encoding.
I tried to use the T5ForConditionalGeneration and GPT2LMHeadModel but both appeared to use there own tokenizers to encode the words of interest. I have already encoded the words though and now trying to deocde what was generated.
One potential solution would be to use an Auto-Encoder but I don't know where to start here. The one that appears to show up the most frequently is TSDAE but I feel like this is not what I am looking for either.
Is there a good repository of examples for Auto-encoders or using TSDAE that can help me in figuring out a good method for decoding word encodings from the Sbert transformers?
Or is this a futile task?
